# Kill vscode from the command line

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I tried to kill the vscode from command line:

```
$ killall vscode
No matching processes belonging to you were found

$ killall "Visual Studio Code"
No matching processes belonging to you were found
```

It does not work?

How could I terminate vscode from command line?

Comment: Have you tried `killall code`?

Comment: `$ killall code
No matching processes belonging to you were found` @MadhanVaradhodiyil

Comment: Which OS are you using ? If you're using windows :  `Taskkill /IM code.exe /F`

Comment: is using macos @MadhanVaradhodiyil

Comment: have you tried [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291328/how-to-killall-visual-studio-code-in-terminal) ?

Comment: this also works just fine `sudo pkill -9 code` as per https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/how+to+kill+vscode+linux

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use

```
killall code
```

It will terminate all running instances of Visual Studio Code.

Comment: sudo killall code; worked for me. Thanks Madhan Varadhodiyil

Comment: No matching processes belonging to you were found -- despite vscode running

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Saved my day. I was going to turnOff the Pc and then turnedItOn.

Answer (score 20):

If nothing works try this

```
$ sudo kill -9 $(pgrep Electron)
```

Use with caution ⚠️ this will also terminate other apps which are run by Electron

Comment: ~  killall code                                                                                                                                                              ✔  at 04:39:51 PM
No matching processes belonging to you were found

 ~  kill -9 $(pgrep Electron)

Comment: @MonaJalal try with sudo might work

Comment: ~  sudo kill -9 $(pgrep Electron)                                                                                         1 ✘  took 3s  at 07:58:18 PM 
worked

Comment: `kill $(pgrep Electron)` was enough for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```html
killall Electron
```

The above command works. But it will kill all your running electron apps.