# how to close correctly a running vscode instance from gitbash for windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, git-bash

how to close correctly a running vscode instance from gitbash for windows?
as if I pressed the closing cross in the top right corner of its window, the same but with a command in a terminal? Thank you

Comment: I know killing is different than closing, but checking just in case- are you are satisfied with any of the answers form https://stackoverflow.com/q/52076242/11107541 ?